# Should a repository return Task<SomeEntity>?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, repository, async-await

I'm designing a repository, but I have this doubt.

Should I design it to be blocking operations or async?

I tend to think that blocking is more elegant, since users can wrap calls to be async when needed with something like

```
Task.Run( () => repository.Get(...));
```

What do you think?

Comment: It no sense if your repository doesn't have logic and only has access to database.

Comment: using async is a good idea, particularly as data access is I/O bound. You need to use async all the way through to obtain full benefit. Avoid using Wait and Result.

Comment: I don't see the point. Why would you want your repository (db, web service, any other source of data) to be blocking? Instead of wrapping repo calls as tasks all over the place you could use repo.Get().Result to block if really needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since underlying data source is naturally asynchronous in most cases (web service, database, file), `async` API is a preferred way.

> blocking is more elegant, since users can wrap calls to be async when needed

Actually, vice versa.
User ([not you](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx)!) can wrap async call into synchronous one, if needed:

```
Task<MyObj> DoSomethingAsync() { ... }
MyObj DoSomething()
{
     return DoSomethingAsync().Result;
}
```

while this:

```
Task.Run( () => repository.Get(...));
```

is called ["async over sync"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) and must be avoided:

> should we expose an asynchronous entry point for a method that’s
>   actually synchronous?  The stance we’ve taken in .NET 4.5 with the
>   Task-based Async Pattern is a staunch “no.”